# Multiple line execution in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to execute the following cypher code:

```
// Nodes created for Lessons, Submitter, Center and Topic
// Relations created 
// Uniqueness constraints.
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (l:Lesson) ASSERT l.name IS UNIQUE;
// Load.
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///llis.csv' AS line
WITH line, SPLIT(line.LessonDate, '-') AS date
CREATE (lesson:Lesson { name: TOINT(line.`LessonId`) } )
SET lesson.year = TOINT(date[0]),
    lesson.month = TOINT(date[1]),
    lesson.day = TOINT(date[2]),
    lesson.title = (line.Title),
    lesson.abstract = (line.Abstract),
    lesson.lesson = (line.Lesson),
    lesson.org = (line.MissionDirectorate),
    lesson.safety = (line.SafetyIssue),
    lesson.url = (line.url)
```

However, I cannot do this in the browser because it's two separate lines. See error:

Node(562) already exists with label `Lesson` and property `name` = 0

I know I am meant to do this in the Neo4j-shell. I have managed to get in to the Neo4j-shell but how do I run this bit of code there?

Answer (score 1):

Put your syntax in a file and then run it as follows :

on Windows

```
type yourfile.cypher | bin\cypher-shell.bat -u <user> -p <password>
```

on Linux

```
cat yourfile.cypher | bin/cypher-shell -u <user> -p <password>
```

Hope this helps,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV data probably has multiple rows with the same `LessionId` value. If so, that would cause a uniqueness constraint violation on `Lesson(name)` each time your `CREATE` clause tries to create a second `Lesson` node with the an existing `name`.

The following version of your `LOAD CSV` query uses `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` to avoid duplicating `Lesson` nodes:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
  LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///llis.csv' AS line
WITH line, SPLIT(line.LessonDate, '-') AS date
MERGE (lesson:Lesson { name: TOINT(line.LessonId) } )
ON CREATE SET
    lesson.year = TOINT(date[0]),
    lesson.month = TOINT(date[1]),
    lesson.day = TOINT(date[2]),
    lesson.title = (line.Title),
    lesson.abstract = (line.Abstract),
    lesson.lesson = (line.Lesson),
    lesson.org = (line.MissionDirectorate),
    lesson.safety = (line.SafetyIssue),
    lesson.url = (line.url);
```

The above query also uses `ON CREATE` to only perform the `SET` operation if the `MERGE` had actually created a node. This effectively causes the query to ignore all lines in the CSV file that repeat a previously seen `LessonId`. If, for some reason, you actually do want the SET to always happen (even for rows with a repeated `LessonId` value), you can omit `ON CREATE`.